# geocode 2 addresses with geocoder gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-geocoder, rails-postgresql

I'm trying to geocode 2 addresses which are asked in 1 form.

```
  <%= f.input :kotadres %>
  <%= f.input :location %>
```

Both of them work with Google Autocomplete like this:

```
<script>
  var input = document.getElementById('student_location');
  var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input,{componentRestrictions: {country:'be'}});
  google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function(){
  var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
  })
</script>

<script>
  var input = document.getElementById('student_kotadres');
  var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input,{componentRestrictions: {country:'be'}});
  google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function(){
  var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
  })
</script>
```

This works perfectly fine, because both addresses are stored in the database.

Now I want to geocode these 2 addresses in my database. It already works for 50%, because for some reason it always geocodes :kotadres into a :latitude and :longitude column but I have no idea why it geocodes only this attribute and not the :location attribute.

This is my Students table:

```
  create_table "students", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "location"
    t.float    "latitude"
    t.float    "longitude"
    t.string   "kotadres"
  end
```

I know I have to create 2 new columns to store 2 new latitude and longitude values for :location but I was wondering how to do this.

Basically I want to understand why it only geocodes the :kotadres attribute and not the :location attribute. I tried the following things:

- swith both input fields in the form (result: only :kotadres gets geocoded)
- delete the :kotadres input field (result: :location doesn't get geocoded)

My Student model looks like this:

```
geocoded_by :location
after_validation :geocode, if: :location_changed?

geocoded_by :kotadres
after_validation :geocode, if: :kotadres_changed?
```

So if someone knows how to geocode these 2 addresses or if someone knows why it always geocodes the :kotadres attribute, I'm more than happy to know the answers.

Comment: You should seriously consider using a separate Address model and setting up a one to many relationship. Your current issue is due too to the fact that you are moshing everything into a single model.

Answer (score 0):

The trick here is not to do everything in a single model:

```
class Student
  has_many :addresses
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses
end

# latitude:float 
# longitude:float
class Address 
  enum type: [:home, :work, :billing] #etc
  belongs_to :student
  geocoded_by :full_street_address 
  after_validation :geocode, if: :full_street_address_changed?
end
```

To setup a form that lets the student setup multiple addresses at once you would do:

```
<%= form_for(@student) do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :addresses do |a| %>
    <%= a.text_field :full_street_address %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

You also need to setup the controller:

```
class StudentsController 

  def new
    @student = Student.new do |s|
      s.addresses.new
      s.addresses.new
    end
  end

  def create
    @student = Student.new(student_params)
  end

  private 

    def student_params
      params.require(:student).permit(
         :foo,
         :bar,
         addresses_attributes: [
           :full_street_address
         ]
      )
    end
end
```

See:

- [Active Record Nested Attributes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html)
- [ActionView::Helpers::FormHelper#fields_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for)
- [Action Controller Overview - nested parameters](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#nested-parameters)

Comment: This is not a drop in fix - rather a nudge in the right direction and will require you to adapt the solution to your situation.

Comment: If you want to keep track of both the users addresses and the current location you would geocode the location on students and addresses separately.